# Portfolio Page Auto Redirect

Tags: wordpress

When i'm trying to add "page/2" to portfolio url page like this :
-http://localhost/WP/portfolio/product-1/
-http://localhost/WP/portfolio/product-1/page/2/
It's automatic redirect back to this:
-http://localhost/WP/portfolio/product-1/

How can i disable this automatic redirection . I'm using portfolio form unyson wp framework . Thanks a lot

Comment: Once again click Save Changes in Setting->Permalink

Comment: i've already update permalink but it's still not working